# Translate coords to re-position dialog box?

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, dialog, gdi

I am hooking `CreateDialogIndirectParam`. I want to do some manipulations over the dialog box, but but the width, height, and x and y positions are in dialog box units. Can someone explain how to convert them to screen coordinates?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [MapDialogRect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. I think it does what you think.

Remember that the mapping depends on the font used by the dialog, so the `HWND` must be that particular dialog.

Also from [GetDialogBaseUnits()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
pixelX = MulDiv(templateunitX, baseunitX, 4);
pixelY = MulDiv(templateunitY, baseunitY, 8);
```

Being `baseunitX` the value `tmAveCharWidth` and `baseUnitY` the value `tmHeight` returned by function [GetTextMetrics()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You just need a `HDC` with the dialog font selected.

Comment: Cant i do the conversion before actually calling the CreateDialogIndirectParam ?

Comment: @Cooker: You can see my updated answer. A bit of extra calculations will be needed, and you will need to get/create the font by yourself.